# Reduce space between spinner item

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-spinner

Any one could suggest how to reduce space between spinner items height having radio buttons.

My Code is below .

Layout

```
  <Spinner android:layout_width="250dp" 
  android:layout_height="40dp" 
  android:id="@+id/spinnerCompany"
  android:theme="@style/SpinnerTheme"  
  android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown" />
```

Spinner Theme

```
<style name="SpinnerTheme">
<item name="android:layout_width" >fill_parent</item>
<item name="android:textSize" >15dp</item>
<item name="android:layout_width" >fill_parent</item>
<!--<item name="colorAccent">#00f</item>
<item name="colorControlNormal">#00f</item>-->
</style>
```

Activity Code

```
ArrayAdapter CompanyAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, cls_static.ToArrayList(ListofCompnyFromDB));
CompanyAdapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SelectDialogSingleChoice);
spinnerCompanyObj.Adapter = (CompanyAdapter);
```

Getting output like below any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `android:dropDownWidth="100dp"` in `Spinner`

```
 <Spinner android:layout_width="250dp" 
    android:dropDownWidth="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp" 
    android:id="@+id/spinnerCompany"
    android:theme="@style/SpinnerTheme"  
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown" />
```

There is running screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have made a minor change like below and it get resolved.

Activity

```
  CompanyAdapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Resource.Drawable.styl_spinner_style);
```

styl_spinner_style

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/text1"
  style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="37dp"
  android:ellipsize="marquee"
  android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
  android:textColor="#252c3b"/>
```

Comment: Yes, you could custom a DropDownView, or you could set the `dropDownWidth` directly, Based on your question, I think set the `dropDownWidth` is a quick way. Please do not forget to mark the answer, it will help others who have simialr issue.